# How to publish to all endpoints in an application platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm working on Amazon SNS and I've hit a wall in how to publish message to all endpoints registered to a specific application platform.

Do I have to create a topic that includes all target endpoints and publish to it?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in this case is to create an SNS topic and subscribe all endpoints to the topic. That way, whenever you publish a message to the topic, SNS will handle fanning it out to all subscribed endpoints for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's what I guessed and I'm glad to hear it.